# Error while trying to install Community Engine: NameError - "Undefined local variable or method 'map'

Tags: ruby, communityengine

I'm trying to install Community Engine using the instructions here: http://github.com/bborn/communityengine

At first I thought it might be because I had Rails 2.3.5 and desert 0.5.3 which were higher versions than what was mentioned on the installation site. However moving to rails 2.3.4 and desert 0.5.2 did not work.

Any ideas as to what might be going on?

```
$ script/generate plugin_migration
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecat
ed and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
/cygdrive/c/users/me/jesse/projects/ceng1/config/routes.rb:2: undefined local variable or method `map' for main:Object (NameError
)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load_without_new_constant
_marking'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load_without_desert'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/ruby/object.rb:18:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/ruby/object.rb:32:in `__each_matching_file'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/ruby/object.rb:17:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `load_routes!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `load_routes!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:266:in `reload!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:537:in `initialize_routing'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:188:in `process'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from /cygdrive/c/users/me/jesse/projects/ceng1/config/environment.rb:6
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from script/generate:3
```

Comment: This is on Windows Vista using cygwin.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I reverted back to 2.3.4 from 2.3.5, but it still does not work!

When i comment out the code in "vendor/plugins/community_engine/config/initializers/sessions_middleware.rb"

Then every command works fine but when I go to localhost:3000, it gives a 500 Internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I figured it out:

The problem is with vendor/rails

do this:

```
rake rails:freeze:gems
```

This works for me!

---

This might be a possible solution:

[Running into issues when running Rails on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265302/running-into-issues-when-running-rails-on-ubuntu)